# Rails Error in Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, terminal

My code was working fine yesterday and then after I reverted some changes from git I am getting this error

```
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated spring 1.3.4, but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.3. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I am unsure how to fix this I have ran the bundle command in terminal with still no luck! Please HELP MEEEE!!!!

Comment: have you tried stopping/restarting spring `./bin/spring stop`?  What files did you revert in git?  Was your gemfile one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer here for anyone looking to solve the same or similar issue:[Couldn't run migration after spring update in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203272/couldnt-run-migration-after-spring-update-in-rails)

You need to run bundle update spring in terminal